# cant use createdb command on bash terminal windows

Tags: sql, postgresql

when i am trying to create postgres database with bash terminal on windows 11, im using below commands;

`createdb 'test'`

or

`createdb -U postgres 'test'`

and nothing happens.

[image]

i added the bin folder to paths in "environment variables" of windows. but it didnt solve the problem.

[image]

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Try without the single quotes

Comment: Both: `createdb -e "TEST"` and `createdb -e 'TEST'` succeeded on Windows. The first creating a database `TEST`, the second creating a database `'TEST'`.

Answer (score 0):

**1st solution**:

- `sudo su - postgres` to become postgres
- `psql -c "create database demo"` to create it from shell

**2nd solution**:

Just simply enter the following commands on bash:

$ `createdb -U postgres(db user) dbname`

If you set hba_config in pg for the access to the db in network type:

$ `createdb -h YOUR_IP -U postgres(db user) dbname`

Lastly, if you set password for db user, pg will ask your password to create database.

**Note**: If nothing works from above, double-check your system environment variables

Answer (score 0):

for me I used Windows command directly, could you first try `cd` directly to your `postgresql bin` folder (I suppose `createdb` application must be there), then try using `createdb` command. If it works, there must be some wrong config with your Env variable :D (need restart, or just reopen your terminal)

[image]

Comment: It is also possible to use the full path like: `"C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\14\bin\createdb.exe" newdbname`  (Because of the spaces in the path you need to put double-quotes around the complete stuff...)    (and `13` or `14` is just a matter of version...)